# Looping through an outer set and using row result for inner set

Tags: mysql

I have two queries:

The first is extremely simplified:

```
SELECT
    c.price_date,
FROM
    cost c
```

Now I need to cross reference this with a 'outer loop' so to speak which is set of results containing dates from another table - a calendar table in effect.

The second query for dates table is straight forward:

```
select * from dates
```

I cannot use traditional joins (the query is more complicated than what I have included above) so I am looking for a way to loop through each row in the date table and use the date in the first query.  I have looed into CROSS and OUTER apply and also Common Table Expressions but mysql version do not support these unfortunateky.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't  see why a simple join would not work - an example would help.

Comment: use database object CURSOR. that allows you to iterate over the rows of a result set, of one query.

Comment: @KashifSolangi Thanks, do you think I need to be concerned when using CURSOR to iterate over approx 1,000 rows?